How do I create an animation where a ribbon is tied?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z6r7dNy85UA
I want to make an animation that comes with this video and makes knots
From what I thought

It's flying with a curve

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aXjzxI6kXY
2.I don't know what to do yet, but I make a ribbon using Cloth simulation
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Za2pUXVDcvI
The existing armature belongs to the side used to move
It's impossible to make a difference
I'm going to make a new armature and work on it
If you turn off the existing armature, you will be out of your original location and go back to your original location, so I don't know what to do
What should I do?
If I'm wrong from the beginning
I'd really appreciate it if you could tell me the whole thing

Hello, you don't even need an armature, just a long subdivided plane that follows a curve thanks to a Curve modifier, then at the end animate the vertices of the curve so it makes the knot (hardest part)

It's true, I don't know why I didn't think of doing this, yes, it's time to do the hard part. Thank you

Well, if you just follow path on the object, there is no deformation on the surface

I'm not talking about a Follow Path constraint but a Curve modifier and you move your plane so that it deforms along the curve

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Create your ribbon, create a curve that draws the path that the ribbon is supposed to follow, give a Curve modifier to your ribbon, move the ribbon so that it deforms along the curve:

As for the knot at the end, that's the hardest part, you'll need to parent each vertex of your curve to an armature bone and animate the bones
